# Make a Form retreive a data from the page it was launch from... Possible?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, dreamweaver, data-retrieval

im using pho forms in dreamweaver, i did a comments form, as in users will be able to comment about the items in my website, each individually. But its the same form for every page, which is why i need for the form to retreive the tittle of the page where it was lauch from... Its like a

```
    $_get and $post
```

I need that when the user clicks on the link "Comment" the form would launch with the Item's Field auntofilled with the item's name which is located in the previous page... Is there a way i can say in php to retreive the Name and paste it in the next page? In php, or maybe in js or anyway... Help!

Comment: Retrieve the name from what?

Comment: "Is there a way i can say in php to retreive the Name and paste it in the next page?" - `$_POST`; `$_GET`; `$_SESSION`;

Comment: I wouldnt be asking if it was that simple... Trust me i hope is just that ... Im looking for the form page to retrieve an specified data from the previous page!

Comment: I think im not explaining my self correctly... What i need is the script for getElementsByTagName... So that when the users clicks to get the form, the title of the page he clicks on would appear already (like an autofill) on the form ... I believe in order to make this work i would have to insert or include somewhere on the code "history.go(-1)" ... Or something like that... Thank you sooo much for your time and helping out!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hundreds of things that may vary from what you are describing.

Are those pages static?

Is there a php that dynamically retrieves them from the database?

Assuming that you already have the PHP variable that prints the title of the "item" you have, it's quite simple. You should just add a field in the form. Something like:

```
<?php 
  print '<input type="hidden" name="item_title" value="'.$item_title_var.'"/>';
?>
```

If your question is about retrieving the item title on each page, without having access to the real page data from PHP, then maybe you can combine the following JS and PHP:

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
  print '<input type="hidden" name="item_title_field" id="item_title_field"/>';
?>
```

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("your_item_title_id");
    document.getElementById("item_title_field").value = el.innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```

Just make sure that there is no actual HTML in the item title, but just the text. It would simplify things for you.

Comment: The entire website is dynamic... im looking for the name of the page (which is equal to the items name, since is a different page for each item, and every page will be linked to the same form), all i want is the form to pick up the name of the previous page... Possible?

Comment: I think im not explaining my self correctly... What i need is the script for getElementsByTagName... So that when the users clicks to get the form, the title of the page he clicks on would appear already (like an autofill) on the form ... I believe in order to make this work i would have to insert or include somewhere on the code "history.go(-1)" ... Or something like that... Thank you sooo much for your time and helping out!!!!

Comment: To avoid loading the previous page, you can use my approach or other similar approaches from other answers to pass on the title in a hidden field to every page you may need it. What you want cannot be done as you describe it. If you want data from a previous page, you just have to pass it on somehow.

Comment: Well thats good to know hehe... Thank You SO much for your time!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a hidden field in each form putting the form's name in it.

For E.g:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_field" value="registration form" />
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['hidden_field'];
?>
```

In this way you can easily get the name of each form.

There are multiple ways to do this but as per your question you looks like **PHP NOOB** so i answered in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, but the name or title that im lloking for is the one from the previous page not the actual form, i want the form to pick up the name of the previous page... Possible?

Comment: I need the form to capture the Title from the previous page

Comment: To capture the title and that would post it in a specific field of the form...

Comment: I think im not explaining my self correctly... What i need is the script for getElementsByTagName... So that when the users clicks to get the form, the title of the page he clicks on would appear already (like an autofill) on the form ... I believe in order to make this work i would have to insert or include somewhere on the code "history.go(-1)" ... Or something like that... Thank you sooo much for your time and helping out!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well. Basically... if you communicate with your server between two pages, all you have to do is submit the information you need for your next page. I say "if" because your pages could also be simple parts showed or hidden via javascript, and I don't know that right now.

See @Moeed Farooqui for more precision.

Comment: I think im not explaining my self correctly... What i need is the script for getElementsByTagName... So that when the users clicks to get the form, the title of the page he clicks on would appear already (like an autofill) on the form ... I believe in order to make this work i would have to insert or include somewhere on the code "history.go(-1)" ... Or something like that... Thank you sooo much for your time and helping out!!!!

Answer (score -1):

you can add an  field on each form and then, when you receive the request you can get the product id with $_POST['product'];

Comment: I think im not explaining my self correctly... What i need is the script for getElementsByTagName... So that when the users clicks to get the form, the title of the page he clicks on would appear already (like an autofill) on the form ... I believe in order to make this work i would have to insert or include somewhere on the code "history.go(-1)" ... Or something like that... Thank you sooo much for your time and helping out!!!!